# C BST Post Order Traversal Using Two Stacks

Tags: c

I am trying to do post order traversal iteratively by using two stacks but to no avail.

I'm not sure why it's not able to push into the second stack of the node popped from the first stack.

Edit: Added push and pop implementation. Please let me know if more details are needed, thank you. Not sure why I can't push the popped node into another stack despite being able to push the initial node to S1

Full code:

https://pastebin.com/01zQxgQf

```
void postOrderIterativeUsingTwoStacks(BSTNode *root)
{
    Stack *S;
    Stack *S2;

    BSTNode *current = root;
    push(S, current);

    while(!isEmpty(S))
    {



        BSTNode *popped_item = pop(S);
        printf("works\n");
        push(S2,popped_item);
        printf("doesn't work\n");

        push(S, popped_item->left);
        push(S, popped_item->right);




    }

    while(!isEmpty(S2))
    {


        printf("%d ", pop(S2));
    }
}

void push(Stack *stack, BSTNode * node)
{
    StackNode *temp;

    temp = malloc(sizeof(StackNode));

    if (temp == NULL)
        return;
    temp->data = node;

    if (stack->top == NULL)
    {
        stack->top = temp;
        temp->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        temp->next = stack->top;
        stack->top = temp;
    }
}


BSTNode * pop(Stack * s)
{
    StackNode *temp, *t;
    BSTNode * ptr;
    ptr = NULL;

    t = s->top;
    if (t != NULL)
    {
        temp = t->next;
        ptr = t->data;

        s->top = temp;
        free(t);
        t = NULL;
    }

    return ptr;
}
```

Comment: `printf("%d ", pop(S2));`. I think `pop()` return a pointer to BSTNode. You may want to print the value of the popped item

Comment: @kuro the issue is I can't seem to  push(S2,popped_item);

Comment: "not able to push" does not clearly describe the problems you are observing. Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as well as exact expected behaviour and actual behaviour.

Comment: @dikolav150 then can you share the function implementation of `push()` and `pop()`? or as @kaylum, said a minimal example would be best

Comment: @kuro sorry, i updated the post

Comment: That's still not enough. Please read the link which describes what we need. Basically, we need to be able to take the code **exactly as shown** and run it to reproduce the problem. Also please tell us what "can't push the popped node" means in terms of the code. Is there a crash? Is there some wrong output? What exactly?

Comment: @kaylum I added pastebin.. hopefully that's no issue.. yes, it crashes when trying to push the node popped from the stack S.

Comment: `push(S2,popped_item);` Consider this - what is the value of `S2` at that point? Use a debugger. These things can be much more easily found using the right tools. The debugger will tell you instantly which line of code triggers the crash and what the variable values are. Can also step thru the code. Those are basic debugging steps.

Comment: @dikolav150, the `S` and `S2` are pointer which are not initialized and the `push()` is trying to access that pointer. This is undefined behavior. The `push()` in `S` can also create problem.

Comment: You need to write a `create_stack` or `init_stack` function that returns an initialised empty stack.

Comment: `if (temp == NULL)
        return;` will have interesting consequences :D